# How do I clone and remove last child with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to clone and remove ul last-child but following code is not working. Someone tell me how it will be work?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    tmp1 = '';
    tmp = '<ul><li><h4>Menu 5</h4></li></ul><ul><li><h4>Menu 6</h4></li></ul><ul><li><h4>Menu 7</h4></li></ul>';
    $(tmp).children('ul:last-child').clone().appendTo(tmp1)
    $(tmp).children('ul:last').remove();
    $('div').append(tmp);
});
```

Comment: The key is in the documentation: _"The .children() method [...] only travels a **single level** down the DOM [...] If the selector is supplied, the elements will be filtered by testing whether they match it"_ -- http://api.jquery.com/children/. You probably want `.last()` since your collection are already `ul`s.

Comment: tmp1 is not doing anything ? after appendto ?

Comment: I will use tmp1 for another process ;) @Ani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are doing it wrong: `tmp` is a string.

You have to do this: http://jsfiddle.net/Lu6jA/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   tmp1 = '';
   tmp = '<ul><li><h4>Menu 5</h4></li></ul><ul><li><h4>Menu 6</h4></li></ul><ul><li><h4>Menu 7</h4></li></ul>';
   var lastUl = tmp.lastIndexOf("<ul>");
   var yourclone = tmp.substring(lastUl);
   var newtmp = tmp.replace(yourclone,"");
   $('div').append(newtmp);
   alert(yourclone);  // This is for your reference
});
```

**Explantion:**
First find the `last UL` from the string. `yourclone` contains your last `ul` as a string. 
Now, replace `last ul` from the `tmp` string with nothing, so basically means remove it and place the result in `newtmp`. the append it to `div`.